# Is it possible to restore a UTF-8 MySQL dump on a latin-1 charset installation?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a myslqdump file created from a UTF-8 database and I want to restore it to a database configured on latin-1

As I don't have root access to the mysql instance, I can't change the default configuration or recreate the database with a UTF-8 config.

Is there a way to import this database ?

Comment: Short answer. No UTF8 can hold chars than latin1 can hold. You can get encoding problems

Comment: Does the dump contain any characters which cannot be represented by Latin-1? Then you can't store that data. But what does "restore" mean exactly? You're restoring only the data into an existing Latin-1 database? Or you're re-creating all the tables in the process too?

Comment: The part I don't understand is why you'd need root access to change the encoding. Encoding can be set at all levels, even session scope. Is there some context that's missing from the question?

Comment: Restore means: mysql -u xxx database < dump.sql

Comment: Álvaro, that's my question: how to import at session level.

Comment: Hi Raymond, but if I assume that all chars can be converted, what would be the command line to import ?

Comment: What does your dump look like? Does it include `CREATE TABLE` statements or tables already exist in target DB? If it includes them, don't they state the encoding of each table?

Comment: It's a regular dump generated by mysqldump -u xxx database > dump.sql

Comment: That means, it contains the drop and the create table. The destination database is empty by the way.

Comment: Those dumps are not binary, you can open the file with a regular text editor. My copy of mysqldump carefully specifies encoding everywhere ([example](https://pastebin.com/sLJ3Bp7H))—I don't know if my defaults depend on the platform or version, or even if they're different from yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and/or No.

If all the text involves only English letters, there is no problem -- the encoding is the same.

If you have some Western European accented letters, the encoding is the different for them.  But this can be handled by correctly specifying the encoding with `SET NAMES` or some other technique.

If you have any Asian characters, punt.

However...  What do you mean by "a latin1 installation"?  Any character column can have any `CHARACTER SET`, so if you specify the *columns* correctly, then there should be no problem.

Please provide more specifics if you need to discuss this further.

Comment: latin-1 is one of the possible character set encoding the database is created. For instance: CREATE DATABASE <schema> CHARACTER SET latin-1

Comment: Old versions of MySQL defaulted to `latin1`; 8.0 defaults to `utf8mb4`.